# Renaming read data in a for loop

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, loops

I need to read data from an excel file which has a large number of sheets. Each sheet has a big dataset from a different year.

The name of the tabs are shown by a year which represent the year of data collection. The data is read as follows:

```
Data_2000 = pd.read_excel('Database.xlsx',sheet_name = 2000)
```

Because there are a lot of sheets, I want to use a for loop to read the data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Database.xlsx', on_demand=True)
SheetName = wb.sheet_names() # Reading the name of the sheets

for i in SheetName: 
   Data = pd.read_excel('Database.xlsx',sheet_name = i )
```

The problem is that I cannot change the name of the data frame, i.e., `Data`, in this loop and set it as `Data_2000`, `Data_2001`,...

Comment: the indentation is incorrect at the last line

Comment: Thats a really bad idea. Use dictionary instead

Comment: If you use `sheet_name=None`, `read_excel` returns a `dict` of `DataFrames`. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#specifying-sheets).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just store your variable in a dictionary like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Database.xlsx', on_demand=True)
SheetName = wb.sheet_names() # Reading the name of the sheets
data = dict()
for i in SheetName: 
  data[f"Data_{i}"] = pd.read_excel('Database.xlsx',sheet_name = i )
```

You can then access the data you want like this:

```
data["Data_2000"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and valuable help. Besides what you have mentioned i also tried the following approach and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to just use dicts.

```
#First set up a dict
sheets = {}


# Then when you run the loop you append to that dict
for name in SheetName:
    data = pd.read_excel('Database.xlsx', sheet_name = name)
    year = name
    sheets[year] = data
```

You can then call the dict using the keys if you need data for a certain year with the format `called_data = sheets[year]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggestions. I also tried the following approach and it worked well and could deliver what I expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Data.xlsx', on_demand=True)
SheetName = wb.sheet_names() # Reading the name of the sheets
for i in SheetName:
globals()['Data_%s' %i] = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', sheet_name = i)
```

It produces different Dataframe keeping Data_ at the binning of the name and put the name of the sheet after that (e.g., Data_2000, Data_2001, ...)